# Reuse Browserstack session in Junit tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit, browserstack

I have been developing JUnit tests using Selenium webdriver and I test them on BrowserStack.

It works when:

1. I keep all my selenium scripts in one test method.
2. I keep my scripts in different JUnit test methods, as they open their own sessions and run smoothly.

I now want each of my Test methods to use the same BrowserStack session (to reduce total run time). Is this possible? I have read somewhere about intern framework a little, but do we have any other simple way to achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure why you are worried about `same BrowserStack session`. As far as `BrowserStack` is concerned it works on the configurations you provide. Have you integrated `Selenium` with `intern framework`?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I could make it work with some code modifications to close driver only when it reaches end of all tests.
We will be having hundreds of tests, hence reusing sessions for certain group of tests - say a particular test set would help and save lot of time and they should be independent too.